# Escaping with ADB and SQLITE, concatenating commands

Tags: android, sqlite, shell, escaping, adb

I'm trying to insert binary data in database of an app running in Android.

I can do it perfectly if I run the command from inside the shell like

```
G011A:/ # sqlite3 /data/data/com.app.test/db/data.db "insert or replace into sessions (record, timestamp) values (X'0a81',1645815520)"
```

It inserts data perfectly. But I need to run it from outside like

```
adb shell 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.app.test/db/data.db "insert or replace into sessions (record, timestamp) values (X'0a81',1645815520)"'
```

And it does not work, it gives me a

```
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected
```

I tried every possible escaping and sequence

```
adb shell "sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp/db/test.db 'insert or replace into sessions (record, timestamp) values (X"0a81",1645815520)'"

WARNING: linker: /mnt/runtime/default/emulated/0/Download/sqlite3: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x8000001

Error: unrecognized token: "0a81"

adb shell 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp/db/test.db "insert or replace into sessions (record, timestamp) values (X'0a81',1645815520)"'
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected


adb shell 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp/db/test.db "insert or replace into sessions (record, timestamp) values (X\'0a81\',1645815520)"'
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected


adb shell 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp/db/test.db \"insert or replace into sessions (record, timestamp) values (X\'0a81\',1645815520)\"'
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected


adb shell "sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp/db/test.db \'insert or replace into sessions (record, timestamp) values (X\'0a81\',1645815520)\'"
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected


adb shell "sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp/db/test.db \'insert or replace into sessions (record, timestamp) values (X\'0a81\',1645815520)\'"
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected
```

Any ideas how to do it?

This more simple query works, as I don't have another ' in the middle of the query

```
adb shell "sqlite3 /data/data/com.app.test/db/data.db 'select * from sessions'"
```

BTW: this a PowerShell terminal running on Windows 10. And I'm later embedding this command line in a Java application.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp/db/test.db <<EOF
insert or replace into test (record, timestamp) values (X'0a81', 1645815520);
EOF
```

##### edit

Or this which is super ugly

```
adb shell echo 'insert or replace into test \(record, timestamp\) values \(X'"\'"'0a81'"\'"', 1645815521\)\;' \| sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp/db/test.db
```

##### edit 2

Use your favorite editor to create a file containing the SQL with nothing escaped (i.e. `my.sql`)

```
insert or replace into sessions (record, timestamp) values (X'0a81',1645815520)
```

push it

```
adb push my.sql /data/local/tmp
```

then

```
adb shell sqlite3 -batch /data/data/com.app.test/db/data.db '<' /data/local/tmp/my.sql
```

Comment: You can install [gitbash](https://gitforwindows.org/) and it will work

Comment: adb shell echo 'select * from sessions' \| sqlite3 /data/data/com.myapp/db/test.db                                                      /system/bin/sh: C:/Program: not found

Comment: I like the workaround you suggested in "edit 2" i'll use it for now. Thanks!

Comment: Although your workaround solved my issue temporarily, my question is still unanswered. I would prefer not to work with files if possible. If no one gives a proper answer I'll mark yours in a few days. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want files the first answer works perfectly on `gitbash`